# How to programmatically access ipad "Video" folder

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, video, ios4

I am using the iPad, and I have videos/movies stored in the "Videos" folder on the iPad.
Note: I'm not try to access videos saved in the Photos Section, I can already access videos saved in here by using;

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
picker.delegate = self; 

[picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]];
```

However this does not access the videos and movies that I have stored in my Videos folder on the iPad. - ones which have been purchased and downloaded via itunes.

Is it possible to get access to this folder? I have upgraded to the new 3.2.5 beta to see if this would help but cannot find a solution.

Anyone know how or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access videos in the ipod library using the SDK. The ipod library access programming guide says the following:

```
 Note: iPod library access applies only to audio-based media items. 
You cannot play video podcasts, movies, or television shows from the iPod library.
```

I beat my head against the wall trying to find this too..